# Protecting user page markup against script insertion and the like

Tags: javascript, html, css, cgi

I am working up a page where I want to let users enter their own HTML into a contenteditable div, which I grab and display upon a button push.

So far:

- They click the "test" button
- I take the content out of the div.innerText
- I scrub it of the word "script", replacing same with `!--`
- I scrub it of the word "exec", replacing with `!--`
- I scrub it of the word "include", replacing with `'!--'`
- I scrub it of the word "virtual", replacing with `'!--'`
- I scrub it of the path to the server's cgi, replacing with `'!--'`
- Then I shovel the rest into another div.innerHTML for display.

As far as that goes, it's working.

Anything else I should be doing to their entered content to prevent script or other maljunkery insertion?

The goal, if possible, is to allow pretty much any HTML or CSS, but disallow script activity. A sandbox where they can mess up the page all they want, intentionally or otherwise, but that is safe as far as the server itself goes.

Comment: A simple regex find and replace will never do the job properly. HTML cannot be described by a regular language.

Comment: Do you care if they run malicious scripts on their own browser?  If you are parsing their input on the frontend your server shouldn't be in danger (anything they run through your div they could inject into the page through the console either way)

Comment: Are you saving it so others can view it?

Comment: Derek, all I'm trying to do is kill scripts and cgi access from the front facing page. If the word script is replaced, can they still run scripts from that div? I'm not trying to check their HTML. Just yank out the executable parts. Are you saying that pulling out the words above still lets them execute from the div?

Comment: epascarello, no.

Comment: lrkenInvader, no... I don't care what they do to their browser on their own machine, but it's entirely possible to launch system cgi programmatically  via javascript entered in such a div, and I don't want to make it that easy for them. Can't stop them from editing the dom, etc., in browsers that (unfortunately) allow that, but right there on the page, I'd just as soon not have them flailing away.

Comment: Why do you scrub? Are you saving the html in a database and show it to other users? Are you running that code on your server? Not sure what you mean by running cgi, a client changes the html on their page should not affect anything on the server. Only sending data to the server could and anyone can write an automated script to check for exploits on your server. Saving html should have you worried about xss: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Comment: HMR, as I already said, I'm not saving anything. "Not sure what you mean by running cgi" you can launch any URL from within javascript. Did you not know that?